# PHP copy file issue

Tags: php, copy

I am having a weird issue here

I am trying to copy file to the folder

```
 if ($folder) {
        codes.....
    } else if (!copy($filename, $root.$file['dest']) && !copy($Image, $root.$imagePath)){
             throw new Exception('Unable to copy file');
    }
```

My question is the `$image` file never gets copied to the destination

However, if I do

```
if ($folder) {
        codes.....
    } else if (!copy($Image, $root.$imagePath)){
             throw new Exception('Unable to copy file');
    }
```

It works.

**Edit:**

**I know the first filename statement is true.**

Can anyone help me to solve this weird issue? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I would suggest using `try {} catch {}`

Comment: "I know the first filename statement is true" - see my answer, and others, below. The second copy isn't happening precisely *because* the first copy succeeds.  || instead of && will fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's all part of an optimization.**

Since `&&` only evaluates to true if **both** conditions evaluate to true, there is no point evaluating (i.e. executing)

```
copy($Image, $root.$imagePath)
```

when

```
!copy($filename, $root.$file['dest'])
```

already returned false.

**As a result:**

If the first copy succeeds, the second copy will not be performed because `!copy(…)` will have been evaluated to false.

**Suggestion:**

```
// Perform the first copy
$copy1 = copy($filename, $root.$file['dest']);

// Perform the second copy (conditionally… or not)
$copy2 = false;        
if ($copy1) {
    $copy2 = copy($Image, $root.$imagePath);
}

// Throw an exception if BOTH copy operations failed
if ((!$copy1) && (!$copy2)){
    throw new Exception('Unable to copy file');
}

// OR throw an exception if one or the other failed (you choose)
if ((!$copy1) || (!$copy2)){
    throw new Exception('Unable to copy file');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, I know the first copy ($filename) is true because I can see the file. Why is the second copy statement wasn't executed?

Comment: @Rouge Yes, exactly. If the first copy returns true, then `!copy(…)` returns false. As a result, the second copy does not happen. The only way for the second copy to happen is for the first to fail (!false -> true).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to say

```
else if (!copy($filename, $root.$file['dest']) || !copy($Image, $root.$imagePath))
```

(note `||` instead of `&&`)

As-is, as soon as the copy succeeds, the `&&` will never be true, so PHP stops evaluating the expression.

In other words,

```
$a = false;
$b = true;
if ($a && $b) {
  // $b doesn't matter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If !copy($filename, $root.$file['dest']) evaluates to false, then there is no reason for php to try to evaluate !copy($Image, $root.$imagePath) because the entire xxx && yyy expression will be false regardless.